# how to get custom type value from session variable in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, class, session

i'm just want to know is there any way to get the custom type value from session variable in jquery?

for example. 
i have a class named user.

```
public class user{
    public string userid;
    public string username;
}

public static class Abc
{
    public static List <user> user; //user type list
}
```

and in session variable i have  session["userclass"] =  Abc.user;

now the question is how to get value from this session variable using jquery.

i know about var abc = <%=session["variablename"]%>

but how to get value of the user class variables using above session variable in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you put:  "session["userclass"] = Abc.user;",

session["userclass"] is a list, not a user object.

You can code as followings:

List u = session["userclass"] as List;

User firstone = u[0] as user;

string id = firstone.userid;

Comment: thanx for your reply. but i want it in jquery......is there any way to get that value from jquery.

Comment: You have to write server side code so jquery calls it to get session object.

Comment: unfirtunately,you can access custom types in javascript via session variable. Keep a separate session variable to get that specific value.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ${FEEDBACK_QUESTION_IDS} this is session attribute name in controller

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        window.questionIdsList = [];
        var i = 0;
        <c:forEach items="${FEEDBACK_QUESTION_IDS}" var="queId">
        questionIdsList[i] = parseInt(${queId});
        i++;
        </c:forEach>

    });
</script>
finally we can use  "window.questionIdsList" as same as array
```